# Is it safe to delete /var/log/node.log?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

I ran out of space in my ubuntu+vagrant environment, then upon checking those large files, i found out that node.log in /var/log/ uses 7.7G, which is enough space I need.

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm         4096 Apr  1 15:21 kern.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       90420 Apr  1 16:54 dpkg.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        28672 Apr  1 16:59 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm        57344 Apr  1 17:01 mail.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root  8219842764 Apr  1 17:01 node.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm    299622400 Apr  1 17:01 syslog
```

My question is it fine to delete this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **safe** to delete a **log file**. However, it is **not safe** to delete a **log directory**. Example of deleting `/var/log/mail/` cause a `File not found` exception when trying to write `/var/log/mail/info.log`. Because the parent directory can not be found.

Although I advise you to empty it instead. [Several other ways to empty a file](https://www.tecmint.com/empty-delete-file-content-linux/).

```
cat /dev/null > /var/log/node.log
```